# Flat database records to parent Child XML transformation

Tags: xslt

I have records in database which has same order header with all lines records
Could anybody please help me how to use xsl to transform

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<getParentChildOutputCollection xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/dbaasdatabase/getParentChild_REQUEST/types">
   <getParentChildOutput>
      <PID>1</PID>
      <PNAME>Xerox</PNAME>
      <CID>101</CID>
      <CNAME>Order 101</CNAME>
      <CDESC>Order Paper</CDESC>
   </getParentChildOutput>
   <getParentChildOutput>
      <PID>1</PID>
      <PNAME>Xerox</PNAME>
      <CID>102</CID>
      <CNAME>Order 102</CNAME>
      <CDESC>Order Black Ink</CDESC>
   </getParentChildOutput>
   <getParentChildOutput>
      <PID>1</PID>
      <PNAME>Xerox</PNAME>
      <CID>103</CID>
      <CNAME>Order 103</CNAME>
      <CDESC>Order Staple Pin</CDESC>
   </getParentChildOutput>
   <getParentChildOutput>
      <PID>2</PID>
      <PNAME>HP</PNAME>
      <CID>230</CID>
      <CNAME>Order 230</CNAME>
      <CDESC>Order Red Ink</CDESC>
   </getParentChildOutput>
   <getParentChildOutput>
      <PID>2</PID>
      <PNAME>HP</PNAME>
      <CID>231</CID>
      <CNAME>Order 231</CNAME>
      <CDESC>Order Blue Ink</CDESC>
   </getParentChildOutput>
</getParentChildOutputCollection>
```

I want to transform above sml using xsl to below output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<request-wrapper>
  <TransmissionID>1234</TransmissionID>

  <DeliveryOrders>
    <OrderCode>1</OrderCode>
    <Company>Xerox</Company>
    <Lines>
      <c1d>101</c1d>
      <cname>Order 101</cname>
      <cdesc>Order Paper</cdesc>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
      <c1d>102</c1d>
      <cname>Order 102</cname>
      <cdesc>Order Black Ink</cdesc>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
      <c1d>3</c1d>
      <cname>Order 103</cname>
      <cdesc>Order Staple Pin</cdesc>
    </Lines>
  </DeliveryOrders>

  <DeliveryOrders>
    <OrderCode>2</OrderCode>
    <Company>p2</Company>
    <Lines>
      <c1d>230</c1d>
      <cname>Order 230</cname>
      <cdesc>Order Red Ink</cdesc>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
      <c1d>231</c1d>
      <cname>Order 231</cname>
      <cdesc>Order Blue Ink</cdesc>
    </Lines>
  </DeliveryOrders>
</request-wrapper>
```

I have used the below xsl but in the application I am working it is not working, it is not recognize the key and generate-id commands. Are there any other way I can acheive this?

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xml:id="id_1" xmlns:nssrcmpr="http://www.oracle.com/2014/03/ics/schedule" xmlns:nstrgdfl="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/ftp/writejson/types" xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/ftp/writejson_REQUEST/types" xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension" xmlns:oracle-xsl-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/mapper/schemas" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.oracle.com/adapters/extension" xmlns:ns5="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/ftp/writejson_REQUEST" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes=" nssrcmpr oraext xsd xp20 ora oracle-xsl-mapper xsi fn ns1 xsl ignore01" xmlns:ignore01="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java" ignore01:ignorexmlids="true" xmlns:nsmpr0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/dbaasdatabase/getParentChild_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr1="http://www.oracle.com/2014/03/ic/integration/metadata" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:ns23="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/ftp/write/response/pull" xmlns:flt="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/service/fault" xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/com.bea.wli.sb.functions.dvm.DVMFunctions" xmlns:orajs0="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1453381219" xmlns:ns22="http://xml.oracle.com/types" xmlns:orajs6="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1211296200" xmlns:orajs3="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath213937888" xmlns:orajs1="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath562866038" xmlns:orajs7="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath86288" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/dbaasdatabase/getParentChild_REQUEST" xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/com.bea.wli.sb.resources.icsxpathfunctions.ICSInstanceTrackingFunctions" xmlns:orajs2="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1600802978" xmlns:orajs5="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath2113524327" xmlns:orajs4="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1290874520" xmlns:ns0="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue">
   <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema xml:id="id_2">
      <!--SPECIFICATION OF MAP SOURCES AND TARGETS, DO NOT MODIFY.-->
      <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources xml:id="id_3">
         <oracle-xsl-mapper:source type="XSD" xml:id="id_4">
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../../processor_13/resourcegroup_14/ICSSchedule_1.xsd" xml:id="id_5"/>
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="schedule" namespace="http://www.oracle.com/2014/03/ics/schedule" xml:id="id_6"/>
         </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>
      <oracle-xsl-mapper:source type="WSDL" xml:id="id_13">
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../../application_27/inbound_28/resourcegroup_29/getParentChild_REQUEST.wsdl" xml:id="id_14"/>
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="getParentChildOutputCollection" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/dbaasdatabase/getParentChild_REQUEST/types" xml:id="id_15"/>
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:param name="getParentChild" xml:id="id_16"/>
         </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>
      </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
      <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets xml:id="id_7">
         <oracle-xsl-mapper:target type="WSDL" xml:id="id_8">
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../../application_49/inbound_50/resourcegroup_51/writejson_REQUEST.wsdl" xml:id="id_9"/>
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="WriteFile" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/ftp/writejson_REQUEST/types" xml:id="id_10"/>
         </oracle-xsl-mapper:target>
      </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets>
      <!--GENERATED BY ORACLE XSL MAPPER 12.1.2.0.0-->
   </oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
   <!--User Editing allowed BELOW this line - DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE-->
   <xsl:param name="getParentChild" xml:id="id_25"/>
   
   <xsl:key name="keyHeader" match="nsmpr0:getParentChildOutput" use="nsmpr0:PID" />
   <xsl:key name="keyLines" match="nsmpr0:getParentChildOutput" use="concat(nsmpr0:PID,'#',nsmpr0:CID)" />   
   
   <xsl:template match="/" xml:id="id_11">
      <nstrgmpr:WriteFile xml:id="id_12">
         <nstrgdfl:request-wrapper xml:id="id_31"> 
            <!--<xsl:for-each xml:id="id_33" select="$getParentChild/nsmpr0:getParentChildOutputCollection/nsmpr0:getParentChildOutput">-->
            <xsl:for-each xml:id="id_33" select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyHeader', nsmpr0:PID)[1])]"> <!--Sreejit 1 -->
               <nstrgdfl:DeliveryOrders xml:id="id_34">
                  <nstrgdfl:OrderCode xml:id="id_40">
                     <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_41" select="nsmpr0:PID"/>
                  </nstrgdfl:OrderCode>
                  <nstrgdfl:Company xml:id="id_38">
                     <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_42" select="nsmpr0:PNAME"/>
                  </nstrgdfl:Company>
             <!-- <xsl:for-each xml:id="id_36" select="."> -->
                <xsl:for-each xml:id="id_36" select="key('keyHeader', nsmpr0:PID)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyLines', concat(nsmpr0:PID,'#',nsmpr0:CID))[1])]"> <!--Sreejit 2 -->
                     <nstrgdfl:Lines xml:id="id_37">
                        <nstrgdfl:c1d xml:id="id_43">
                           <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_44" select="nsmpr0:CID"/>
                        </nstrgdfl:c1d>
                        <nstrgdfl:cname xml:id="id_45">
                           <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_46" select="nsmpr0:CNAME"/>
                        </nstrgdfl:cname>
                        <nstrgdfl:cdesc xml:id="id_47">
                           <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_48" select="nsmpr0:CDESC"/>
                        </nstrgdfl:cdesc>
                     </nstrgdfl:Lines>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </nstrgdfl:DeliveryOrders>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </nstrgdfl:request-wrapper>
      </nstrgmpr:WriteFile>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Regards,
Sree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each xml:id="id_33" select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyHeader', nsmpr0:PID)[1])]">
```

selects nothing because there is no element named `row` in the current context (or in the entire input document, for that matter).

---

Side note: your stylesheet is tagged `version="2.0"` yet you are attempting to use Muenchian grouping - which makes very little sense.

Comment: thanks Michael for the help, you are correct I have changed row to `<xsl:for-each xml:id="id_33" select="nsmpr0:getParentChildOutput[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyHeader', nsmpr0:PID)[1])]"> `

Comment: you mentioned that I am using  Muenchian grouping in version="2.0", sorry I am new to this, so are there any other way to do in version 2.0? Please advise or help

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you can use `xsl:for-each-group` - see: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted the code which worked, just for others in case anybody want the code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xml:id="id_1" xmlns:nssrcmpr="http://www.oracle.com/2014/03/ics/schedule" xmlns:nstrgdfl="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/ftp/writejson/types" xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/ftp/writejson_REQUEST/types" xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension" xmlns:oracle-xsl-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/mapper/schemas" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.oracle.com/adapters/extension" xmlns:ns5="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/ftp/writejson_REQUEST" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes=" nssrcmpr oraext xsd xp20 ora oracle-xsl-mapper xsi fn ns1 xsl ignore01" xmlns:ignore01="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java" ignore01:ignorexmlids="true" xmlns:nsmpr0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/dbaasdatabase/getParentChild_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr1="http://www.oracle.com/2014/03/ic/integration/metadata" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:ns23="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/ftp/write/response/pull" xmlns:flt="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/service/fault" xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/com.bea.wli.sb.functions.dvm.DVMFunctions" xmlns:orajs0="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1453381219" xmlns:ns22="http://xml.oracle.com/types" xmlns:orajs6="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1211296200" xmlns:orajs3="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath213937888" xmlns:orajs1="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath562866038" xmlns:orajs7="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath86288" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/dbaasdatabase/getParentChild_REQUEST" xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/com.bea.wli.sb.resources.icsxpathfunctions.ICSInstanceTrackingFunctions" xmlns:orajs2="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1600802978" xmlns:orajs5="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath2113524327" xmlns:orajs4="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1290874520" xmlns:ns0="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue">
    <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema xml:id="id_2">
        <!--SPECIFICATION OF MAP SOURCES AND TARGETS, DO NOT MODIFY.-->
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources xml:id="id_3">
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:source type="XSD" xml:id="id_4">
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../../processor_13/resourcegroup_14/ICSSchedule_1.xsd" xml:id="id_5"/>
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="schedule" namespace="http://www.oracle.com/2014/03/ics/schedule" xml:id="id_6"/>
            </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:source type="WSDL" xml:id="id_13">
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../../application_27/inbound_28/resourcegroup_29/getParentChild_REQUEST.wsdl" xml:id="id_14"/>
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="getParentChildOutputCollection" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/dbaasdatabase/getParentChild_REQUEST/types" xml:id="id_15"/>
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:param name="getParentChild" xml:id="id_16"/>
            </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>
        </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets xml:id="id_7">
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:target type="WSDL" xml:id="id_8">
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../../application_49/inbound_50/resourcegroup_51/writejson_REQUEST.wsdl" xml:id="id_9"/>
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="WriteFile" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/ftp/writejson_REQUEST/types" xml:id="id_10"/>
            </oracle-xsl-mapper:target>
        </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets>
        <!--GENERATED BY ORACLE XSL MAPPER 12.1.2.0.0-->
    </oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
    <!--User Editing allowed BELOW this line - DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE-->
    <xsl:param name="getParentChild" xml:id="id_25"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" xml:id="id_11">
        <nstrgmpr:WriteFile xml:id="id_12">
            <nstrgdfl:request-wrapper xml:id="id_31">
                <xsl:for-each-group xml:id="id_33" select="$getParentChild/nsmpr0:getParentChildOutputCollection/nsmpr0:getParentChildOutput" group-by="nsmpr0:PID">
                    <nstrgdfl:DeliveryOrders xml:id="id_34">
                        <nstrgdfl:OrderCode xml:id="id_40">
                            <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_41" select="nsmpr0:PID"/>
                        </nstrgdfl:OrderCode>
                        <nstrgdfl:Company xml:id="id_38">
                            <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_42" select="nsmpr0:PNAME"/>
                        </nstrgdfl:Company>
                        <xsl:for-each select="fn:current-group()">
                            <nstrgdfl:Lines xml:id="id_37">
                                <nstrgdfl:c1d xml:id="id_43">
                                    <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_44" select="nsmpr0:CID"/>
                                </nstrgdfl:c1d>
                                <nstrgdfl:cname xml:id="id_45">
                                    <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_46" select="nsmpr0:CNAME"/>
                                </nstrgdfl:cname>
                                <nstrgdfl:cdesc xml:id="id_47">
                                    <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_48" select="nsmpr0:CDESC"/>
                                </nstrgdfl:cdesc>
                            </nstrgdfl:Lines>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </nstrgdfl:DeliveryOrders>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </nstrgdfl:request-wrapper>
        </nstrgmpr:WriteFile>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```